# Qt Static Building

Tags: c++, windows, qt, build

It says [on the Qt documentation](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/deployment-windows.html) to open up a command prompt and `cd C:\path\to\Qt`. What is path\to\Qt? What kind of command prompt am I to open up? A regular one or a Qt one? Someone please explain the whole process to me like I'm a beginner, because I am.

**Edit:** In my "C:\QtSDK", there is no such file called configure. However, there is a "configure.bat" in `C:\QtSDK\Symbian\SDKs\Symbian1Qt473`. I tried that and nothing seemed to happen. Then I tried `nmake sub-src` like instructed on the website, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to get Qt for Windows not just the QtSDK which is geared for mobile targets. like Symbian.  Follow the directions on this page: http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/install-win.html to get started.

Comment: Under step 2 They say to uncompress "the files" to the directory you want Qt installed. Where is the archive that i download?

Comment: The downloads page is http://qt.nokia.com/downloads  You probably want the full Windows download (which I see they call the Qt SDK, so it looks like my answer isn't quite right).  You might also be able to get away with one of the Qt libraries downloads further down the page.